# Looping through a Column if it has a certain name

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file, there is a macro that copies all the data from Sheet1 and pastes it to Sheet2 in a certain order.

Problem: Sometimes the file will be updated with additional Columns so it will need to paste that data into a certain column from sheet 1 into sheet 2, and example will be If Sheet1 has a value of NewData1, copy all the data in that column and paste it to sheet 2. This has to be copied by Name and not the position in sheet 1

I have used Cells.Find to find the name of the Column, now all i need is to copy the values in that entire column and paste it into the new sheet

**UPDATED CODE BELOW**

```
Set res = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:="NewData1")
If Not res Is Nothing Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range(Cells(2, res), Cells(50, res)) 'SOMETHING LIKE THIS
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 9).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

**UPDATE EXPECTATIONS**

```
ColA    ColB       ColC
Hello   Goodbye    How are you
Hi      Bye        Are you well
Hey     Seeya      You ok
```

If NewData1 is added to this and it looks like this:

```
ColA    ColB       ColC           NewData1
Hello   Goodbye    How are you    Im new
Hi      Bye        Are you well   So am i
Hey     Seeya      You ok         Me Too
```

I need to copy that data and paste it to the other sheet, the problem is it may not be the 4th column of the sheet, it may be 5th 6th or 7th. This is why i am looking to copy by Cell Value

**UPDATE 2**
Re edited the code, is there something similar to this that could be done?

Comment: It would be better to post the code you have, as a start.

Comment: Plus some examples showing what you want.

Comment: Updated accordingly

Comment: Updated the question with something i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can start by firstly storing the number of columns in the current dataset, then work with that, thats just a start however:

```
Dim n As Long

n = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Additionally, why dont you just do a copy paste of the dynamic ranged dataset everytime?

Comment: Careful - it would be `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` (the `Columns.Count` needs the sheet ref. too)

Comment: As long as `Sheets("Sheet1")` is the active sheet, it should work.  However, change sheets and then run, it should throw an error.  Without the explicit sheet reference when using range objects (`Range()`, `Cells()`, `Columns()`, `Rows()`, etc.), it's best to include the sheet explicitly, otherwise it's going to use the active sheet.

Comment: The organizing of data aspect seems like a good idea, maybe if i can organise the columns to specific columns , i.e paste the Newdata to colum AE i could then set my range to A1:A500 and paste to sheet2

Comment: @BruceWayne it will only through an error if the activesheet has less columns than sheet1.  Otherwise it will work.  ***It is still good practice to ensure no conflicts.***

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah, thanks for clarifying that for me!